# Update user info in View Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have an extension class includes method like this:

```
public static string GetName(this IPrincipal user)
    {
        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = user.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            foreach (var claim in claimsIdentity.Claims)
            {
                if (claim.Type == "Name")
                {
                    return claim.Value;
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
        else
            return "";
    }
```

After call action to update User table include `Name`, the name called by `@User.GetName()` not update although column in database has change.

If user logout system and login again, the name display in view changed as the last update.

I have a solution to logout and login again after class action to update user info. Is there other solutions without logout?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of using claims is they're a snapshot of user information.

If you check your startup.cs class you will see validateInterval. This is the interval in which your claims get refreshed. You can inforce this earlier by updating the users security GUID.

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
```